# What is the difference between pytz.all_timezones and pytz.all_timezones_set?

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

I stumbled across pytz.all_timezones_set, but I'm confused about several of its features.
After printing both, this was my output:
all_timezones:`['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa']`(I'm only showing the first 3 elements, to save space.)

all_timezones_set:`LazySet({'America/Menominee', 'Indian/Maldives', 'America/Nome'})`(Again, only the first 3 elements).

My questions:

1. What is a LazySet? I know that it isn't a built-in feature, so pytz must have defined it, but for what purpose?
2. What are the differences between both of these? They look fairly similar, besides different naming conventions and the LazySet. When are these differences useful?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you look at the [src](https://github.com/stub42/pytz/blob/master/src/pytz/lazy.py#L71), it's subclassed from the built-in type, but populated on first use. not sure about the purpose though...